# How to assert the correct exception with TestRestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, spring-boot-test

I'm new to TestRestTemplate and with in Spring framework in general, and I'm trying to verify if a ResponseStatusException is thrown by my controller. For example the following degenerated request:

```
@RestController
public class UserManagementController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> updateUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO, @PathVariable("id") String id){
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "user not found");
    }
}
```

And in my test I'm using `TestRestTemplate`:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class UserManagementComponentTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateStaleUser() {
          UserDTO updateUserDTORequest = UserDTO.builder();
          assertThrows(ResponseStatusException.class,
                () -> testRestTemplate.exchange("/users/" + createdUserId,
                HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(updateUserDTORequest), UserDTO.class));
    }
}
```

I expect to get `ResponseStatusException`, but the tests fails with the following message:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException> but was: <org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException>
```

I don't understand why `RestClientException` is thrown.

Comment: `ResponseStatusException` is only used inside your controller. That status code is then sent over the wire as a response to the client (in your case the `TestRestTemplate`). The `RestTemplate` converts 4xx and 5xx status codes to `HttpClientErrorException` resp. `HttpServerErrorException`. Which are subclasses of `RestClientException`. So it is quite clear why your assertion for `ResponseStatusException` fails

Answer (score 2):

`ResponseStatusException` is the exception thrown in the server side and it will be handled by the `spring-mvc` framework in the server internally to return the suitable HTTP error response.

While `TestRestTemplate` just like a client-side REST library and hence it never can catch and handle the exception that is thrown internally from the API server.

`TestRestTemplate` can only throw its own exception when handling the HTTP response returned from calling an API. It will delegate to its internal `RestTemplate` 's `ResponseErrorHandler` for handling the error HTTP response.

So `RestClientException` is thrown by the `ResponseErrorHandler` that you configured for the `TestRestTemplate`.

Actually by default , the `TestRestTemplate` is configured to be fault tolerant such that it behaves in a test-friendly way by not throwing exceptions such that you can asserting directly on the returned HTTP status code or payload (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.utilities.test-rest-template)) :

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.exchange("/users/" + createdUserId, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(updateUserDTORequest), UserDTO.class));

assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(xxxxx);
```